# option "final" in beamerposter

Tags: beamerposter

What is the role of "final" in

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer}
\usepackage[size=a0,orientation=portrait]{beamerposter}
```

?  It seems nothing changes when I remove it.  Thank you.

Comment: The `microtype` package handles a `final` option (as opposed to `draft`). Maybe this is a leftover from a previous version of the document that used `microtype` (or another package that handles `final`), or it was carried over via copy/paste from such a document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find a hint on a class or package option `final` in neither the `beamer` or `beamerposter` documentation nor in the respective `.cls` or `.sty` file. I'd therefore assume that the option `final` is not known and not used and therefore has no effect on the output.

Other document classes such as `article` throw a warning upon using an unknown option. This is shown by the following MWE that gives this warning: `LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s):[abcdef].`

```
\documentclass[abcdef]{article}
\begin{document}
some text
\end{document}
```

If one tries the same nonsense option with the `beamer` class (as in the following example), no warning message is generated:

```
\documentclass[abcdef]{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Some text
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```